# How to iterate through ASP .NET textboxes using javascript and calculate a value?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

i have a multiple textboxes in repeater and i will enter value in those textboxes at runtime. and i want sum of all value entered in those textboxes in one label.i want to do this thing using java script.  so can u please help me.

Comment: This is not the place where you ask for finished code. Try to code it, then ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: There's a discussion of this topic on the [JQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/textboxes-in-asp-repeater-with-total-row) which might help.

Comment: Somebody please rename this. And maybe retag. And some more info wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one idea to get you started:

1. Put a `<div>` around your `Repeater` and give it a unique `id`.
2. Use the `document.getElementById()` function in JavaScript to obtain a reference to that `<div>`.
3. Use the `getElementsByTagName()` function in the DOM element to find all `<input>`s within.
4. Loop over them, adding their values (parsed as integers) together.

So if your markup looks something like this:

```
<div id="coolStuff">
    <asp:Repeater ... >
</div>
```

The JavaScript looks approximately like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("coolStuff");
var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName("input");

var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    sum += inputs[i].value;
}

alert(sum);
```

Now, this code does not check to ensure that the `<input>`s are actually of `type=text` or to confirm that the entered values are numbers. Those parts are left as exercises for the reader ;)

---

*Edit:* If you have multiple text boxes in each "line" outputted by the `Repeater` and you only want to sum the values for one "group" of boxes, you will need to change the script a bit.  Here are two possible solutions - pick one:

1. If you know exactly how many `<input>` elements you have in each "line", you can change the `for` loop in the client script to only visit every Nth element. Eg. to select only the last of three fields in each line: `for (var i = 2; i < inputs.length; i += 3)`
2. Change your markup to include a `class` attribute on the `<input>` elements to be part of the sum. Within the `for` loop, do a test on `inputs[i].className` to verify if the particular field is to be included.

Comment: you all right but i have 3 different coulmn.if i do this logic then 
it will do sum for all text boxes.for that i want txext box by it's unique id.but when i do container.getElementByID.it's not supported.
it only support container.getElementTagName.i want 3 different sum for 3 difefrent coulmn.and if i do simple document.getelementID() it also not works becoz in repeater they generate different id for all text boxes.is there any way to get that different id's in loop.

Comment: `container.getElementById()` (notice lower-case d) *is* supported, but it will not help you here. The value for the `id` attribute on the `<input>` is determined by ASP.NET and it is really unique, across the entire page.

Comment: @Nikunj: I have updated my answer with some ideas for how to get around the additional requirement presented in your comment.

Comment: finally i used this.because using this i can identify textbox using class.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/07/sum-html-textbox-values-using-jquery-javascript.html

Answer (score 2):

Something like so, assuming that you want to sum all textboxes in the repeater control. This will only sum number values too.

```
var repeater = document.getElementById('repeater_id');
var inputs = repeater.getElementsByTagName('input');
var sum = 0;
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === "text" && /^\d+$/.test(inputs[i].value)) {
        sum += inputs[i].value;
    }
}
```

If you're doing a lot of client-side stuff, why not take a look at doing this with a library, such as jQuery.

Comment: you all right but i have 3 different coulmn.if i do this logic then it will do sum for all text boxes.for that i want txext box by it's unique id.but when i do container.getElementByID.it's not supported. it only support container.getElementTagName.i want 3 different sum for 3 difefrent coulmn.and if i do simple document.getelementID() it also not works becoz in repeater they generate different id for all text boxes.is there any way to get that different id's in loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" CssClass="rpt">
<itemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" />
</itemTemplate>
<footerTemplate>
  <asp:Label Id="lblResult" CssClass="result" />
</footerTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

javascript using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.rpt input[type=text]').live('onchange', calc);
});

function calc(){
  var result = 0;
 $('.rpt input[type=text]').each(function(){
  // need better input cleaning here...
  result += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('.rpt .result').val(result);
}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Get jQuery. 
Add a class to the textbox in the repeater markup using eg CssClass ='totals'. Use the following jQuery code to total the values

```
var total = 0;
$('input.totals').each(function(){

 if (!isNan($(this).text())) total += $(this).text()
});

alert('Total is ' + total);
```